# Is it possible to OPTIMIZE FOR a specific table variable 'value'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Let's presume I have the following query running on SQL Server 2016:

```
declare @Ids as table
(
    Id int
)

-- Insert some values into @Ids table

select
    *
from dbo.Foos
where FooId in (select Id from @Ids)
```

Now let's presume I want to `OPTIMIZE FOR` a specific 'value' of @Ids table.
Is is even possible to provide such hint? I've tried `option (optimize for (@Ids = (values(1), (2))))`, but it does not compile

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the bottleneck of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use that option such a way. Let's have a look at the documentation:

> OPTIMIZE FOR ( *@variable_name* { UNKNOWN | = **literal_constant** } [ ,
>   ...n ] ) Instructs the query optimizer to use a particular value for **a**
>   **local variable** when the query is compiled and optimized. The value is
>   used only during query optimization, and not during query execution.
>
> *@variable_name* Is the name of **a local variable** used in a query, to which a value may be assigned for use with the OPTIMIZE FOR query
>   hint.

So, that option is for a local variable but not for a table variable which is an absolutely different thing.

[Hints (Transact-SQL) - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017)